# .htaccess redirect from '/profile.php?u=some_name' to '/some_name'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to make a social networking site, and am using apache with php with `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` enabled, please suggest a method to do the 301 redirect and recognition of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile\.php\?u=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```